# forget a network in Wifi Settings does NOT update Configured List

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

Lets consider user forgets a Router "R1" from Wifi Settings.
Now when I access list of all configured routers using :

```
wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
```

"R1"was still present among the list. So When we Forget a router, Will it not get removed from Configured List ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about my solution, but you can check if it works for you or not. `getConfiguredNetworks()` returns a `List` of `WifiConfiguration` objects, these objects has [status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#status) field, that, I think, can be compared to the fields of [WifiConfiguration.Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.Status.html) object. So, please try the following:

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for (WifiConfiguration x : list) {
    if (x.status != WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you manually ['forget'](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-101-how-forget-wifi-network) a network it is removed from your configuration list.  This can happen by adding the network programmatically and also added the network using the native android WiFi configuration manager.

The native Wifi Configuration manager does not add the BSSID of the access point.  My application did add the BSSID to the access point.  The native WiFi controller accepted both.  However, when presented with the configuration option to forget, the OS would only forget one.

I fixed this by [wiping all my configurations](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-quick-and-easy-android-network-security-reset/) and fixing my code to not add the network programmatically if the same SSID is already in configuration and in range.